# Rails - How can I insert the user_id to a comment on a post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Probably a simple question, but I'm just learning Rails and tryin to get comments to post to my database. When I post, no error is thrown but the record is not created.

```
def create

    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:comment))

    redirect_to post_path(@post)

end
```

Posts and comments have a typical nested relationship. I believe the problem lays with a column in my comments table called 'user_id' that should store the relationship of a comment to a user.

How can I set this column in the above code to have the value of 'current_user'?

Many thanks,
Michael.

Comment: Which authentication gem are you using?

Comment: if your `controller` has knowledge of `current_user` then you can do `@comment.user_id = current_user.id; @comment.save` else you would have to add it as an hidden field to the form where `comments` is created from

Comment: So, doing it that way would mean I shouldn't use the create method?

Comment: Any luck with this so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combining previous answers, try

```
@post   = current_user.posts.find(params[:comment][:post_id])
@comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment].permit(:comment))
@comment.save!
```

or perhaps

```
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment].permit(:comment))
@comment.user_id = current_user.id
@comment.save!
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your form already supplies post_id and that you are using the Rails Tutorial method "current_user", plus that the user supposingly `has_many :posts`, you can fill all of the fields with this code:

```
@post   = current_user.posts.find(params[:comment][:post_id])
@comment= @post.comments.create(params[:comment][:comment])
```